# How can we get NPE, race condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked the following question on an interview. Given the following code, if methods `add` and `doAction` are being invoked by multiple threads, how can we get a `NullPointerException` when printing `toString`?**

```
public class Test{
     private List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();

     public void add(Object o){
           obj.add(o);
     }

     public void doAction(){
           for(Object o: obj){
                 System.out.println(o.toString()); // maybe NPE, why?
           }
     }

}
```

Cut out all other multithread concerns.

Comment: Sounds like they are asking you to either know about or speculate on how `ArrayList` is implemented.  The short answer (which might not be what they're looking for) is, "Since `ArrayList` is not thread-safe, it's behavior would be _undefined_."

Comment: Coming from C#, I would expect a [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), but not a NullPointerException

Comment: Yes, I said that CME triggered. But they asked me about NPE... I said maybe yes...

Comment: @jameslarge: I hear "undefined" so often lately. Just because we don't know what happens does not make it undefined. All that managed code, the runtime, exception handling etc. make things pretty predictable, doesn't it?

Comment: Undefined, right. But possible behaviour can be guessed.

Comment: What part of a multithreaded environment do you consider "predictable"?

Comment: I think this is a slightly open ended question. Are you sure you're not missing another detail of the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's change the name of the variable; `List<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();` because "obj" is a really awful name for a variable that refers to a `List`.

OK, When the program calls `list.add(o);`, it may need to grow the array.  That means it's got to:

1. Allocate a new, bigger array whose members all will be initialized to `null`, and
2. Copy the elements from the old array to the new array.,

If thread A is doing that while at the same time thread B is calling `iterator.next()`, thread B could end up reading a `null` value from the new array even *after* thread A has already copied an object reference into that member of the array.

Remember:  When threads access memory with no synchronization, then it is possible for a reader thread to see updates to variables/fields/array members happen in a *different order* from the program order in which the writing thread actually performed them.

Answer (score 4):

```
Test t = new Test();
t.add(null);
t.doAction(); //NPE triggered
```

No nullability guarentees on the `obj` list, so it might contain null values.

Regarding the problem with multithreading refers to the `ConcurrentModificationException` since the "for-all" look uses an `Iterator` internally. If an element is added while iterating it will cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: @St.Antario Added explanation about the multithreading problem.

Comment: Yes, CME is simple to notice. But how can NPE be thrown because of memory inconsistency or other multithread concerns?

Comment: If the size of the list is synchronized before the contents it might read a `null` value, which would be a race condition. I'm personally not sure if the JVM memory model allows for this to happen.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like this question because it implies knowing implementation of the `ArrayList`.

If we are assuming the `Object` being passed is not null then you'd have to reason with code. Here is what add looks like

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

So how can it happen? Well imagine the `size` field is incremented successfully but the assignment `elementData` isn't yet available to the reading thread.

In this case the iterator would `size` number of elements exist and can return a null one (as it hasn't finished writing).

Essentially, it's two steps

1. Increment size
2. Write elementData[size] = e

(1) can succeed while (2) is still in flight.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way:

- Objects in `obj` are mutable.
- The `.toString` method looks at some of the mutable fields and fails if that field is `null`, or maybe when the field is `null` and some other condition does not hold. Quite possibly, the methods of the object mutate it so that after the method's completion, the state of the object is consistent and `.toString` would not fail.
- Another thread mutates the instance being printed. While the mutation is halfway through, and the state of the object is inconsistent, `.toString` is called by another thread, and the call ends up with an NPE.

It's hard to tell without a stacktrace.